# "by the bytes" vs "in bytes"

Tags: c++, coding-style, comments

```
template<class CharType>
struct StringWithLength
{
    size_t    length;
    CharType* str_buf;
};
```

I want to add some comments on the field length. I have two choices:

```
#1. "The field length is the size of str_buf by the byte" 
    (Consider "The worker is paid by the hour")

#2. "The field length is the size of str_buf in bytes"
```

Which is more natural from the viewpoint of a native English speaker?

Thanks.

Comment: How about "length gives the number of bytes in the buffer pointed to by str_buf"?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to be the number of characters, not bytes?

Comment: @Mankarse, I mean no matter what type CharType is, length is always in bytes.

Comment: Does it really need a comment?

Comment: @xmllmx: In that case, `bytes` would be a better name - and wouldn't need extra documentation. Calling it `length` when it's not the length of the string is a recipe for confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't use either. I'd say something like:

> The value of the `length` field is the size of the buffer, in bytes.

The field itself isn't "represented in bytes" any more than *all* data in a computer is. It's the buffer size (or text size, or whatever) which is in bytes.

Comment: Why is "The worker is paid by the hour" more common than "the worker is paid in hours"? Thanks.

Comment: @xmllmx: Well they're paid *in* pounds or dollars etc... but it's a number of dollars *per* hour. I don't think it's a very close comparison to this situation, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a native English speaker, however I've spoken English for 10+ years and lived in an English speaking country for that long, so I would say, from my experience it would be #2 that is more natural.

Comment: Is "by the byte" grammatically correct?

Comment: I don't know all definitions of *by*, but if you can find one that fits your construct, then I think that would grammatically make sense. I'm no language expert though.